# Compact pingback list with favicons

Tags: theme-development, comments, pingbacks, favicon, icon

On a blog with pingbacks and trackbacks (pings) enabled I want to show just a link with link text and a favicon of the external site in a compact list: no date, no text.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first you do: separate regular comments and pingbacks. In your `comments.php` set the type parameter for both:

```
<ol class="commentlist">
<?php
// show regular comments
wp_list_comments(
    array (
        'type'     => 'comment',
        'style'    => 'ul'
    )
);
?></ol>

<ol class="pinglist">
<?php
// show pingbacks and trackbacks, short: "pings"
wp_list_comments(
    array (
        'type'     => 'pings',
        'style'    => 'ul'
    )
);
?></ol>
```

Now, there is a problem: You don’t want to print an empty `<ol>` if there are no approved pings.

So I let’s use a simple ping counter:

```
/**
 * Count amount of pingbacks + trackbacks for a post.
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID for comment query. Default is current post.
 * @return int
 */
function t5_count_pings( $post_id = NULL )
{
    $pings    = 0;
    $comments = FALSE;

    if ( NULL !== $post_id )
    {
        $comments = get_comments(
            array (
                'post_id' => $post_id, # Note: post_ID will not work!
                'status'  => 'approve'
            )
        );
    }
    elseif ( ! empty ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->comments ) )
    {
        $comments = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->comments;
    }

    if ( ! $comments )
        return 0;

    foreach ( $comments as $c )
        if ( in_array ( $c->comment_type, array ( 'pingback', 'trackback' ) ) )
            $pings += 1;

    return $pings;
}
```

Now we wrap our ping list into a conditional:

```
if ( $num = t5_count_pings() )
{
?>
<h2 id="pingbacks"><?php
    printf( _n( 'One pingback', '%d pingbacks', $num, 't5_theme' ), $num );
?></h2>
<ol class="pinglist">
<?php
wp_list_comments(
    array (
        'type'     => 'pings',
        'style'    => 'ul'
    )
);
?></ol>
<?php
}
```

If `t5_count_pings()` returns a `0`, PHP will read that like a `FALSE` and the list container will not be printed.

Now the formatting. `wp_list_comments()` accepts a parameter `callback`, and we can use that to render the content of each ping. I named mine `t5_list_pings_callback()` and add it like this:

```
wp_list_comments(
    array (
        'type'     => 'pings',
        'style'    => 'ul',
        'callback' => 't5_list_pings_callback'
    )
);
```

The content of this function is very simple:

```
/**
 * Callback for wp_list_comments( array ( 'type' => 'pings' ) )
 *
 * @param  object $comment
 * @return string
 */
function t5_list_pings_callback( $comment )
{
    $url     = esc_url( $comment->comment_author_url );
    $icon    = t5_external_favicon( $url );
    $name    = esc_html( $comment->comment_author );

    print "<li><a href='$url'>$icon $name</a>";
}
```

Two important notes:

1. Do not add the closing `</li>`. WordPress will do that for you.
2. We need a function `t5_external_favicon()`. Let’s ask Google.

.

```
/**
 * Get an img element for a favicon from Google.
 *
 * @param  string $url
 * @param  string $class class attribute
 * @param  int    $size
 * @param  string $alt
 * @return string
 */
function t5_external_favicon( $url, $class = 'icon', $size = 16, $alt = '' )
{
    $host     = parse_url( $url,  PHP_URL_HOST );
    $icon_url = "https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain=$host";

    return "<img class='$class' width='$size' height='$size' alt='$alt' src='$icon_url' />";
}
```

We use an empty `alt` attribute because the images are really just decoration. And the `width` and `height` should always be set, because some sites use really large icons.

And that’s it. This is how it looks on `wpkrauts.com`:

[image: screenshot]